# Get all geolocations by partial name using google maps api

Tags: google-maps

I have signed up with the Google Maps API. I can geolocate locations using the following query

```
url = f"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={city}&key={api_key}"
```

I need  to do a search for towns by partial name.

For example 'MyTown' is a town , but there are also towns with names which include 'MyTown' in the title,  such as MyTown-By-Sea, MyTown-SomethingElse and even NiceMyTown

The above query using the API returns just the city MyTown, not the others

Is there some option I have missed to get the Google Maps API to be less specific in the response returned ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Places Autocomplete API web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete). This API will return places suggestions or predictions, based on your given input.

```
  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json
  ?input=MyTown (based on your example)  
  &location=latitude,longitude
  &key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative,
" Not From " Google maps API but useful to get the location coordinates of a certain city

Steps Below
Use Open Weather API to get location coordinates by querying the city name

1. Open on your browser https://openweathermap.org/price
2. Create account after clicking the Get API Key on the pricing table
3. Save the API key
4. Go to https://openweathermap.org/current#name, for more on the query parameters

The base sample API_URL = [https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid={your_api_key}](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=%7Byour_api_key%7D)